# Debugging JavaScript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

Before you mark this as duplicate, please note that the other questions are all over a year old. We are in 2011, and we still don't have half a decent I.E. debugger like Firebug. The only few solutions are paid.

Are there any tools I am missing? How do you go about debugging JS in IE?

Comment: Strongly depends on the browser version. Since IE8 the "IE Developer tools" are free and useful.

Comment: @jAndy the IE Developer Toolbar does not have any equivalent to Net in Firebug. Or do I not know how to activate it?

Answer (score 3):

IE has the IE Developer toolbar. It's been available since IE7. It's not as good as Firebug but it's better than nothing and it's getting better with each version

Forgot to include the link : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

Comment: Is there a way to see the AJAX calls and their outputs?

Comment: Not sure about the IE9 version, but sadly the IE8 doesn't have a net panel

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Tools of IE8. You even got a `console` object to log with. And in IE8 you can switch to IE7 engine.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).
Also, IE9 comes with a full fledged JS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with using just logging rather than a full-on debugger, you could use a cross-browser logging library such as my own [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).